# Load specific indexes of array in Spring 3 XML?

Tags: spring

I am trying initialize a boolean[] in my spring (v3) xml.  The catch is that I need to load specific indexes of that array.  For example, i want to load bArray below:

```
  boolean[10] bArray;

  bArray[Options.AUTO]=true;
  bArray[Options.AIR]=false;
  bArray[Options.FOOT]=false;
```

I've seen example like the one below, but this example does not define the index of the value.

```
<bean id="MyBean" class="org.test.Autos">
    <property name="lists">
        <util:list list-class="java.util.ArrayList">
            <value>true</value>
            <value>false</value>
            <value>false</value>
        </util:list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Can this be done in Spring xml?  Thanks

Comment: Have you tried Java `@Configuration` and doing it... in Java, but still inside Spring container?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean, but I do not have access to the code of the calling class (org.test.Autos in my example).  I may end up writing a class to wrap the one and just create instance variables that map to each of the positions in the array.  is that what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of what Tomasz means by using the `@Configuration` annotation :

First you need to define the `AutosConfiguration` class :

```
@Configuration
public class AutosConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public boolean[] b_Array() {
        boolean[] bArray = new boolean[10];
        bArray[Options.AUTO]=true;
        bArray[Options.AIR]=false;
        bArray[Options.FOOT]=false;
        return bArray;
    }
}
```

You will use this class to specify a custom configuration for the `bArray` variable.

Then you need to configure your spring context :

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.my.pack" />

<bean id="MyBean" class="org.test.Autos">
    <property name="bArray" ref="b_Array" />
</bean>
```

where com.my.pack is the package where the `AutosConfiguration` class is found.

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I was clear.  My challenge is that I NEED to define the values in XML (so they can be changed without a code change).  So, something like:
        <util:array array-class="java.lang.String">
            <entry index="2">true</entry>
            <entry index="4">false</entry>
            <entry index="7">false</entry>
        </util:array>